# Homework: Diffrentiate between 2 toads

Tags: homework, reproduction, differentiation

> How to differentiate between 2 toads one of them result of artificial parthenogenesis and the other from renucleation?

I answered that the toad resulting from artificial parthenogensis is identical to the mother

While the other toad which result from renucleation is identical to that which the nucleus was taken from

My answer is so unrealistic and I can't find any other answer so I though I could use some help.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. What data do you have access to make the differentiation? What frog species? If you could explain what's your interest behind the question, it may help.

Comment: I recommend looking at the tags again

Comment: Oh indeed.... Is it the entire homework question exactly as phrased, or is there more information around it? I don't want to be pedantic but make sure to quote correctly. You can highlight a quote is a quote by starting the line with `>`

Comment: Sorry I am new  .The question is exactly as its phrased

Comment: No worries. It is part of being new to Biology.SE to have its post reviewed, corrected, clarified and sometimes closed. I edited you post. Please note that homework questions are allowed on Biology.SE only if the OP is displaying its attempt at answering the question. So, in its current form your post should get closed. Can you please add your thoughts about this question? On top of protecting the site from "do my job" type of question, it also allow us to understand what level of understanding the OP have and what is unclear for the OP.

Comment: Going to edit it now . Thx